# Change default display where new files appear on desktop

Tags: windows, desktop

I have a three monitor setup. When i save a file to the desktop they always appear on the center screen. Since that's my main screen, the files are usually behind an application.

Is there some way I can change the default behavior so that new files instead appear on the left screen desktop?

Comment: I don't have time to double-check right now, but I know some of the multi-desktop managers have features along those lines.  I'm almost positive [nview](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nview_display_us.html) does, though you would need a compatible nVidia graphics card to use it.

Comment: Seems like that only works for Win7, since Win8 no longer has Aero :(